# gazebo plugin undefined symbol

Tags: gazebo, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to make a gazebo plugin work now. The plugin compiles just fine but when I run it, it gives the the following errors:
undefined symbol: _ZN6gazebo18GazeboRosApiPlugin16spawnGazeboModelERN11gazebo_msgs18SpawnModelRequest_ISaIvEEERNS1_19SpawnModelResponse_IS3_EE

Does anyone know what causes the problem? Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48598/gazebo-plugin-undefined-symbol/) by [shuai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3402/shuai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out... I forgot to uncomment the definition of spawngazebomodel function. I think that the problem is I declared the function but didn't define it. So the library cannot actually use it.

---

Originally posted by [shuai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3402/shuai/) with karma: 46 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1